# Simulate and fire enter keypress in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, triggers

I am currently trying to run a number of automated (simple) JS tests on a website and I would like to simulate and trigger an enter key press on an input field (its not in a form and I would not like to use a form, as I do not wish to edit the code). I've been trying stuff along the lines of:

```
$('#inputField').trigger($.Event('keypress', { which: 13, keyCode: 13 }));
```

I've gone through countless answers on the internet, none have helped and I was wondering if someone could suggest why as this should be a trivial matter.

- Using Chrome v. 49
- Can use JQuery

Thanks.

Comment: did you try this? `$('#inputField').trigger("keydown", { which: 13 });`

Comment: And what is going wrong? [Check this](https://jsfiddle.net/njn73vyx/).